# Appendix creating blank page after section heading while including PDF

Tags: pdf, appendices

I am trying to create an appendix for my thesis that should include few PDF files under proper section heading and appear accordingly in TOC. The three problems I am facing are--

1. The page number is in Arabic continuation, while I need appendix pages in Roman.
2. The word Appendix appears twice in TOC if I give the chapter heading as Appendix A. If I name the chapter as 'A' only, the header following the pages remains 'A', not Appendix A.[See the screenshot].
3. There is an unnecessary substantial blank space between the section heading and the included PDF page (Even if the PDF is scaled down)[See the screenshot]. Probably, this is the default behaviour of {pdfpages} package. **This is my primary problem**. As a result, the header and footer remain missing if multiple PDF pages are included under the same section.
   I know it is proper to ask only one question per thread, but as these are closely related, I thought to group them. Splitting them will require repeating 90% of this content under a different thread.

The present output screen

[image: Repeated]

[image: Ga]

```
    \documentclass[listof=totoc,a4paper,11pt,oneside,chapterprefix=true,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}

    %Header Footer
    \usepackage[automark,headsepline,markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \usepackage[page,toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}
    \automark[chapter]{chapter}
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
    \setkomafont{pagefoot}{\bfseries\small}
    \ohead{\headmark}

    \lefoot*{\pagemark{} \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip} Page}
    \rofoot*{Page \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip} \pagemark}
    \ifoot*{MAKAUT, WB}
    \AddToHook{cmd/mainmatter/after}{%
      \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}% instead of plain → manual
      \pagestyle{empty}%
    }
    \AddToHook{cmd/mainmatter/after}{%
      \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}%
      \pagestyle{headings}%
    }
    \usepackage[margin=1in,head=27.2pt]{geometry}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{acronym}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % for underline with normalem option
    \usepackage{ragged2e} % For justified text
    \usepackage[center]{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[section]{placeins}
    \usepackage{multicol}% used for the two-column index
    \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
    % Example
    \hypersetup{
      colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
      urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
      linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
      citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
    }
    % Define a new font command
    \newcommand{\setchapterfont}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}
    % Patch the \mainmatter command to change font settings
    \preto{\mainmatter}{\setchapterfont}
    
    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftables
    \listoffigures
    \mainmatter
    %\include{Introduction}
    %\include{Literature}
    %\include{chapter8}
    \backmatter
    %\printbibliography
    \begin{appendices}
    \addchap{Appendix A}\label{A}
    \addsec{Plagiarism Certificate}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.8]{./Certificates/Plag_cert.pdf}
    \addsec{Enrollment Certificate}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.8]{./Certificates/Enrollment.pdf}
    \addsec{Coursework Certificate}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.8]{./Certificates/Coursework_completion.pdf}
    \addsec{Registration Certificate}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.8]{./Certificates/Registration.pdf} 
    \chapter{Appendix B}\label{B}
    \section{Journals}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Journals/EVOS_Published.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Journals/wpc.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Journals/sensors.pdf}
    \section{Conferences}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Conferences/Haldia_cert.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Conferences/Haldia.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Conferences/Thermo_cert.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Conferences/Thermometer.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Conferences/Brainware_cert.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Conferences/Brainware.pdf}
    \section{Book Chapter}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Books/Book1.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Books/Book2.pdf}
    \section{International Patent}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Patents/Patent Certificate1.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Patents/Patent Certificate2.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={1},scale=0.7]{./Patents/SA Patent Certificate.pdf}
    \section{Public recognition}
    %\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Patents/TOI.pdf}
    \end{appendices}
    \end{document}
'''
```

Comment: \includepdf always create a new page. Use \includegraphics intead.

Comment: don't put three question in one question. Split them.  And shorten your code. All these packages and definitions are not needed to present your question.

Comment: Thank You Fischer, did'nt have an idea that graphics can be used to include PDF. I simply changed to \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, angle=0]{myfile.pdf}. Works fine if section contains only one PDF. However, multiple PDF is producing a garbled output. Seems like need to experiment with scale factor of each.

Comment: The packeges and code that may have effect on chapter, page number and headings are included, as per my limited knowledge on LaTeX. In case some of them creates any conflict with the solution.

Comment: While `\frontmatter` contains `\pagenumbering{roman}`, `\backmatter` does not (presumably optional).

Comment: You can lose the duplicate "Appendix" by removing the `titletoc` option of the appendix package.

Comment: Thanks, John. Your quick tips resolved the issues successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer courtesy Ulrike Fischer and John Kormylo

1. `\includepdf` always creates a new page. Use `\includegraphics` instead.
2. You can lose the duplicate "Appendix" by removing the titletoc option of the appendix package.
3. Include `\pagenumbering{roman}` immediately after `\backmatter` .

So my revised code is below--

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,a4paper,11pt,oneside,chapterprefix=true,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%%%%%%%%%Header Footer
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[page,toc,title]{appendix}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\bfseries\small}
\ohead{\headmark}
\lefoot*{\pagemark{} \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip} Page}
\rofoot*{Page \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip} \pagemark}
\ifoot*{MAKAUT, WB}
\AddToHook{cmd/mainmatter/after}{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}% instead of plain → manual
  \pagestyle{empty}%
}
\AddToHook{cmd/mainmatter/after}{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}%
  \pagestyle{headings}%
}
\usepackage[margin=1in,head=27.2pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % for underline with normalem option
\usepackage{ragged2e} % For justified text
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{multicol}% used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
% Example
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
}
% Define a new font command
\newcommand{\setchapterfont}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}
% Patch the \mainmatter command to change font settings
\preto{\mainmatter}{\setchapterfont}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
%\include{Introduction}
%\include{Literature}
%\include{chapter3}
%\include{chapter4}
%\include{chapter5}
%\include{chapter6}
%\include{chapter7}
%\include{chapter8}
\backmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\printbibliography
\begin{appendices}
\addchap{Appendix A}\label{A}
\addsec{Plagiarism Certificate}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, angle=0]{./Certificates/Plag_cert.pdf}
\addsec{Enrollment Certificate}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, angle=0]{./Certificates/Enrollment.pdf}
\addsec{Coursework Certificate}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0.5]{./Certificates/Coursework_completion.pdf}
\addsec{Registration Certificate}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0.5]{./Certificates/Registration.pdf}
\addchap{Appendix B}\label{B}
\addsec{Journals}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, angle=0]{./Journals/EVOS_Published.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Journals/wpc.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Journals/sensors.pdf}
\newpage
\addsec{Conferences}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Conferences/Haldia_cert.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Conferences/Haldia.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Conferences/Thermo_cert.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Conferences/Thermometer.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Conferences/Brainware_cert.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Conferences/Brainware.pdf}
\newpage
\addsec{Book Chapter}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Books/Book1.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Books/Book2.pdf}
\newpage
\addsec{International Patent}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Patents/Patent Certificate1.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Patents/Patent Certificate2.pdf}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Patents/SA Patent Certificate.pdf}
\newpage
\addsec{Public recognition}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, angle=0]{./Patents/TOI.pdf}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```